# iOS Swift: Formatting a custom Currency Number

Tags: ios, swift, string, formatting, nsnumber

## Formatting large numbers with comma separator.

#### Solved (The code is updated and fully working)

Evening, I have a typealias `Currency` from `Double`.

I want to print it with the comma between the thousands.

this is what I did:

```
import Foundation

typealias Currency = Double

extension Currency {
    var credit: Double { return self }
    var usd: Double { return self * 0.62 }
    
    func description() -> String {
        let price = self as NSNumber
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter.string(from: price)!
    }
    
}

let price: Currency = 1000000000

print(price.description) 
/* It doesn't work, I want something like 1000,000,000.0 */
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`description` is a property that comes baked into Foundation via the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol which states the `description` variable as:

> A textual representation of the value.

You're looking to call your `description()` method. Add parentheses and you'll get your desired result:

`price.description()`

Comment: We've all been there :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function `description` and I think it'll work as you expected if you call `price.description()`. It looks like you intended to override the default behavior of a `CustomStringConvertable` type but that uses a `var description: String { get }` property, not a function.

Comment: As you just saw `description` is a somewhat troublesome function name since it so closely matches an existing property. You might want to choose a more distinct and meaningful name or explicitly override the `CustomStringConvertable` property getter in your extension.

I hate to hear you wasted 30 minutes. Next time consider if setting a breakpoint and stepping through into the function you expected to call might have helped catch this sort of problem?